# How to update GCP instance object using java SDK?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform

I want to add more data disks to existing VM instance object using java SDK.
Below are my sample code:

```
 Compute.Instances.Get getinstance = compute.instances().get(projectId, zone, instanceName);
 Instance instance = getinstance.execute();
 AttachedDisk dataDisk = new AttachedDisk();        
    dataDisk.setSource("projects/project/zones/zone/disks/diskName");
    dataDisk.setType("PERSISTENT");
    dataDisk.setMode("READ_WRITE");
    dataDisk.setAutoDelete(true);
   instance.getDisks().add(attacheddisk);
```

But I didn't see any method in compute service for update/put.Can any one help on this.
I know how to do update the instance by using Rest API,But i want do this by java sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach instance using methods of `Compute.Instances` class only. These methods will update the instance during execution.

```
AttachedDisk dataDisk = new AttachedDisk();        
dataDisk.setSource("projects/project/zones/zone/disks/diskName");
dataDisk.setType("PERSISTENT");
dataDisk.setMode("READ_WRITE");
dataDisk.setAutoDelete(true);

//attach disk to instance

Compute.Instances.AttachDisk attachDisk=compute.instances().attachDisk(projectId, zone, instanceName, dataDisk);
```

To attach multiple disk, I don't think there is any method exposed in java API. You would have to call `attachDisk()`

To check LUN `AttachDisk` class provides `getIndex()`, where 0 is reserved for boot disk. [Check the link for more information on LUN in GCP](https://cloud.google.com/docs/compare/data-centers/storage#storage_area_network_san).

Comment: Thanks for the replay, but here  I can add only one disk at a time, If i want to add multiple disks i have to call this API for multiple times, this will impact on the performance, is there any API to update all the disks at a time? like in GCP console we can add  multiple disks at a time.And also i want to know the LUN of the attached disk, would it be possible to know the LUN  of the attached disk?

Comment: I don't think there is any method exposed in existing java API, for LUN ```AttachedDisk``` class provides ```getIndex()``` where 0 is reserved for boot disk